# Port forwarding not working at all even when all inputs are correct

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, isp

I have been trying to port forward my modem, unfortunately ONLY the ports in the UNPN list actually work, bad thing is, you cannot add ports to the UNPN list, there is no button or option to do so in the modem, you are however able to have Ipv4 port rules, wich do not work in the slightest [check images]

I'm using a Proximus B-BOX3 and now also an Asus AX53u router [being connected to this and port forwarding also does not work]

how do I open these ports, or how do I FORCE the ports to work, or add things to UNPN without the router UI?

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

[image: modem image1]

[image: modem image2]

Comment: whats going on with your DHCP ranges ? You have a server on 192.168.50.124, and another on 192.168.1.18. What is the routers WAN port attached to, and what is your DHCP range, and subnet? Once I know these I may have a better idea as to what is going on. Both those routers work well with port forwarding so the uPNP ports should work fine, so the problem may lie elsewhere.